# The distance in comparative constructions

Tags: word-choice, word-order, comparative-constructions

Consider:

> Studies have shown those mothers who talk with their babies during pregnancy will make closer and warmer relationship with their babies during/in postpartum **than others/those who don't**.

Is a correct and natural place for "than others who don't"? I think the gap is too long, but don't know where else to put it.

By the way you may help me with the word choices shown with slashes.

Comment: Location of the phrase is fine. Use *those* since you already used it in "those mothers". And since "postpartum" refers to a period of time after birth, use *during*.

Comment: Also, "relationship" should be "relationship**s**".

Comment: It's grammatical, but you are right to identify the sentence as one that could be simplified and improved by restructuring. As always, do not paint yourself into a corner. You can begin the sentence differently. You can start it with "Mothers", for example, or with "Closer bonds".  P.S. You can make **postpartum** an adjective.  Closer postpartum bonds are....